# Using Seq function in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 columns, valuation date and expiry date, I want to create another column repayment dates by using the seq function in R passing the valuation date, expiry date and `by=1/freq`

Below is a function I wrote to create the dates through seq function:

I get the following error

> Error in seq.default(as.yearmon(st), as.yearmon(en), by = 1/freq) :
>   'by' must be of length 1

```
DateSeq <- function(st, en, freq) {
  freq <- ifelse(freq > 0, freq, 1) 
  st <- as.Date(st) 
  en <- as.Date(en) 
  dateseq <- as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(st), as.yearmon(en), by = 1/freq), frac = 1)
  #if (st!=dateseq[1]){dateseq<-c(st,dateseq)} 
  dateseq[1] <- st 
  if (en > dateseq[length(dateseq)]) { 
    dateseq <- c(dateseq, en) 
  } 
  if (en < dateseq[length(dateseq)]) { 
    dateseq <- c(dateseq[-length(dateseq)], en) 
  } 
  dateseq 
}

repayment_dates <- DateSeq(s, e, f)
```

For a validation date of 26-06-2018, and expiry date of 30-Mar-2018, frequency=12, I should get

```
26-06-2018
31-07-2018
31-08-2018
30-09-2018
31-10-2018
30-11-2018
31-12-2018
31-01-2019
28-02-2019
31-03-2019
30-04-2019
31-05-2019
30-06-2019
31-07-2019
31-08-2019
30-09-2019
31-10-2019
30-11-2019
31-12-2019
31-01-2020
29-02-2020
30-03-2020
```

Comment: when i run the above i get an error stating  Error in seq.default(as.yearmon(st), as.yearmon(en), by = 1/freq) : 
  'by' must be of length 1

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataframe.) Also, please make what `freq` is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had two issues: one in the function itself, and one in the the inputs. First, the dates were being formatted incorrectly inside the function, which was causing trouble for `seq()` and throwing errors related to the `by` argument. You need to tell `as.Date()` the format of the dates you're providing, so here is a full (revised) function:

```
DateSeq <- function(st, en, freq) {
  library(zoo)
  freq <- ifelse(freq > 0, freq, 1) 
  st <- as.Date(st, format="%d-%m-%Y") 
  en <- as.Date(en, format="%d-%m-%Y") 
  dateseq <- as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(st), as.yearmon(en), by = 1/freq), frac = 1)
  #if (st!=dateseq[1]){dateseq<-c(st,dateseq)} 
  dateseq[1] <- st 
  if (en > dateseq[length(dateseq)]) { 
    dateseq <- c(dateseq, en) 
  } 
  if (en < dateseq[length(dateseq)]) { 
    dateseq <- c(dateseq[-length(dateseq)], en) 
  } 
  dateseq
}
```

Second, the end date you provide in the question (30-Mar-2018) is before the start date you provide. which I think was also causing problems. Here is a full call and output which matches your desired output.

```
s <- "26-06-2018"
e <- "30-03-2020"
f <- 12
repayment_dates <- DateSeq(s, e, f)

#Output
> repayment_dates
 [1] "2018-06-26" "2018-07-31" "2018-08-31" "2018-09-30" "2018-10-31" "2018-11-30"
 [7] "2018-12-31" "2019-01-31" "2019-02-28" "2019-03-31" "2019-04-30" "2019-05-31"
[13] "2019-06-30" "2019-07-31" "2019-08-31" "2019-09-30" "2019-10-31" "2019-11-30"
[19] "2019-12-31" "2020-01-31" "2020-02-29" "2020-03-30"
```

Comment: i did provide the format and it gives me the same error , i called the function using repayment_dates <- DateSeq(s, e, f) , s is the start date , e is the end date and f is the frequency

Comment: @narayanpr23, I've updated my answer above to be more complete and show exactly what I'm calling. Are you still getting the same error after running the code I'm supplying?